# Music album art not showing up: How to reset?

Tags: mp3, windows-media-player, music, album-art

I have added album art to all my songs, but they’re not showing up. I think I need to clear some directory of its content, but am not sure which one.

I also appended some album art through Windows Media Player, which I think further deepened the problem as most of my songs have no album art at all or have a shared album art.

I need a full reset. If there’s no album art in song, I really want it to be blank even when it's opened in a music player. If there is an album art, I want it to show up in Windows icons.

Comment: You should probably download and install Mp3tag. Windows Media Player doesn't actually insert the album art into the MP3. Mp3tag can do that. I use it a lot to do just that after I rip an album with WMP. Mp3tag can be found here: http://www.mp3tag.de/en/

Comment: What did you use to add the album art? What's the file type of your music files? Which version of Windows are you running?